# Запись 36-ричной системы счисление javascript

Tags: javascript

Как записать 36-ричную систему? к примеру 2,8,10,16 пишутся так: 0b, 0x, 0o. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Не так. В 36-ричной системе это `2`, `8`, `a` и `g`.

Comment: `(16).toSting(36)`  например